# Rails 3.0 with "or" statement in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build a query that compares two object, and if they have the same `id` the record is not fetched. What I have is this:

```
@channels.each do |channel|
  unless @guide_channels.where(:id => channel.id).exists?
    @dropdown_channels = @dropdown_channels.where(:id => channel.id)
  end
end
```

This creates the query, but puts a AND between every value which isn't what I have in mind. I want the "or" operator. Is there a 'orwhere' function I can use or is there a better way to do this with some compare function?

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong `@dropdown_channels = @dropdown_channels.where(:id => channel.id)` is it correct assign you are assigning/reassigning the `dropdown_channels` inside the each block is it correct correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: 1) why use Ruby for that? it seems something to do as AR query 2) `x = x.method` is usually a bad idea

Comment: I agree with tokland, seems like it would be neater / more efficient with a nice join query. Can you give a bit more information on your models and what you're aiming for?

Comment: @tokland this is not true. As long as you don't enumerate or evaluate the query (using `first`, `each`, `to_a`, or print it) the query is perfectly fine to modify, and in fact it is the recommended way to build complex queries in ActiveRecord 3. The point is that the queries built this way have an implicit `AND` between the conditions.

Comment: @rewritten: of course it works, my point was about good programming practices: the less rebinds/in-place-updates a code has, the more clear it is. `x = x.something` is mathematically nonsensical.

Comment: Still don't agree. `x = x + 1` makes perfectly sense, as `=` is assignment, not equality. And that's just a method call. When in-place-updating methods are available, of course it's better to use them (`Hash#update`, `Array#delete_if`), and in Rails 4 you will have in-place-updating bang-methods for relations: `@dropdown_channels.where!(condition)`. Until that, you can trade modularity and configurability (chaining methods) for speed (building a hash and applying it at the end)

Comment: @tokland In the end, chaining methods or building hashes won't solve the OP issue, so we'd better meet with a couple of beers to discuss philosophy... :)

Comment: To everyone who are wondering what my goal is with this thing :
I have one dropdownmenu with channels(tv-channels) , and a "add button" I wanted a way to filter out the channels that where added from the drop-down-list

Comment: @rewritten: noone will discuss it, it makes sense in the imperative programming paradigm, yes. More about `x = x + 1` http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/pdc2008/TL11 ;-)

Comment: @tokland very interesting watch indeed, not applicable in this context. I hope next time you're in Barcelona or me in Asturias we can really have a good conversation about programming paradigms. I surely have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that the `.where()` method of a `AR::Relation` objects adds the condition to a set of conditions that are then `AND`-ed together when the query is executed.

What you have to do is a query like `NOT IN`:

```
# select all the ids for related @guide_channels
# if @channels comes from a query (so it's a ActiveRecord::Relation):
guide_ids = @guide_channels.where(:id => @channels.pluck(:id)).pluck(:id)
#  use .where(:id => @channels.map {|c| c.id}) instead if @channels is just an array

# then use the list to exclude results from the following.
@dropdown_channels = @dropdown_channels.where("id NOT IN (?)", guide_ids.to_a)
```

The first query will accumulate all the IDs for channels that have an entry in `@guide_channels`. The second one will use the result of the first to exclude the found channels from tthe results for the dropdown.

Comment: Smart i didn't know you could use the .where on an existing record

Comment: In retroperspective i now see that this is the way to do it. It will get everything with one query and therefore create the least server load

Answer (score 0):

This strange behavior is due to ActiveRecord's lazy evaluation of scopes.
What happens is that the line

```
@dropdown_channels = @dropdown_channels.where(:id => channel.id)
```

Does not send a query to the DB until you actually use the value of `@dropdown_channels`,  and when you do it concatenates all the conditions into one big query, this is why you get the AND between the conditions.

In order to force ActiveRecord to eager load the scope you can use either the `all` scope or the `first` scope, for example:

```
@dropdown_channels = @dropdown_channels.where(:id => channel.id).first
```

This will force ActiveRecord to calculate the query on spot returning the result immediately and not to accumulate the scopes for lazy evaluation.

Another approach could be to accumulate all those channels_ids and get them later in one query, instead of making a query for each one. This approach is more cost-effective relating to DB resources.
In order to achieve this :

```
dropdown_channels_ids = []
@channels.each do |channel|
  unless @guide_channels.where(:id => channel.id).exists?
    dropdown_channels_ids << channel.id
  end
end
@dropdown_channels = @dropdown_channels.where(:id => dropdown_channels_ids)
```

Comment: Eventually i went with this approach. Using the "<<" seems like the cleenest way to write this. However i miss a "or where" selector which  i have used in other db-adapters

Comment: I don't agree at all, you are getting N queries using this!!! Each of the element in `@channels` will spawn an additional query (potentially hogging your database). With my solution you use exactly 2 queries under any condition to get your results.

Comment: No , the .where() doesn't execute querie untill i call the @dropdown_channels.all in the form, if we are talking about the second example here?

Comment: Are you sure? I'm speaking about the `@guide_channels.where(:id => channel.id).exists?` query.

Comment: Try to run it with `@channels` an array of 25 channels (not a very high number indeed)

Comment: so "@guide_channels.where(:id => channel.id).exists?" executes an query? thought it just checked the object for that record. Then you are right, it is not optimal.

Is there a way to ask the object if record exist? What is the syntax for that?

Comment: Check my answer. You can get the IDs to exclude using just one query, and then a `NOT IN` SQL clause to do the exclusion.